# Install arch linux guide - boot loader instructions

Tags: arch-linux, boot-loader

I am following the arch linux install instructions and all goes fine til i hit the section on boot loaders [https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/installation_guide#Boot_loader) . The section on boot loaders just links to a page about the features of boot loaders, but has nothing on that  page about configuring boot loaders.

```
Boot loader
See Category:Boot loaders for available choices and configurations.
```

Is there an example of how to do this or do I just have to learn about boot loaders? I know not to expect hand holding with arch linux but this seems really  obscure. I this an oversight? Where should I be looking to learn more?

Comment: Have you tried to click on the names of the different boot loaders? Each of em has an own page describing the install and further configuration [like here for grub bootloader](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"...or do I just have to learn about boot loaders?" Yes, that's the whole point of using Arch Linux. You learn how to configure your own system and you end up with a highly configurable system.

Distributions like Antergos and Manjaro give a running desktop based on Arch Linux if you'd prefer to have an already running desktop.

The install guide doesn't give you a default boot loader because different people have different needs. On UEFI systems you don't even need a bootloader while most distributions will use GRUB just in case.

It's my advice since you are just learning to start with GRUB.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB

Comment: "Distributions like Antegros" have a completely different philosophy to Arch Linux.

Comment: After reading the about section of Antergos I would have to agree. Removing that.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation if you are installing Arch Linux on a UEFI system is to use systemd-boot. Systemd-boot is much simpler, because GRUB on UEFI contains a lot of redundant functionality. Systemd-boot is much simpler to configure and understand than GRUB. See the [Arch Wiki systemd-boot](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd-boot) page for installation instructions.